# Corda Tokens SDK: "There is a token group with no assigned command" error

Tags: corda

**I already solved this problem**, but I would like to understand why it occurred in the first place:
1. I'm using the **Java** template of Tokens SDK
2. I created my own token type
3. I modified `ExampleFlowWithFixedToken` class to issue my new token
4. When I ran `start ExampleFlowWithFixedToken amount: 100, recipient: PartyB`, I got the error: **There is a token group with no assigned command**
5. Initially my new token class didn't implement the `equals()` method, when I added it; the error was gone and I was able to issue my token.

Why adding that method, fixes the problem?

```java
public class MyTokenType implements TokenType {

    private final int fractionDigits = 6;
    private final String tokenIdentifier = "MY_TOKEN";

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public BigDecimal getDisplayTokenSize() {
        return BigDecimal.ONE.scaleByPowerOfTen(-fractionDigits);
    }

    @Override
    public int getFractionDigits() {
        return fractionDigits;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Class<?> getTokenClass() {
        return this.getClass();
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String getTokenIdentifier() {
        return tokenIdentifier;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof MyTokenType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExampleFlowWithFixedToken calls the built-in IssueTokens Flow. 
This flow , builds the transaction internally specifying input, output states, commands(IssueCommand in this case). 
Next step is to verify the contract.

Before verifying the contracts we group the input/output tokens by the issuer. 
Each group is then assigned a token command. 
This is done because if a transaction contains more than one type of token, they need to grouped by IssuedTokenType. 
Also note same token type issued by different issuers are not fungible. 
Hence the grouping by IssuedTokenType is required. 
Once we have the groups by IssuedTokenType, contract verification is done separately for each group.

When we try to assign a token command to each group , we compare the IssuedTokenType in command to one in our groups. 
So if we dont override equals method, none of the IssuedTokenType from the groups will match to the one in the TokenCommand.

Hence the group will not be assigned any TokenCommand. 
Each group should at least have one command. If there isn’t then we would not know what to do with that group. Hence it fails saying "There is a token group with no assigned command"

Hope that helps!